# Qual é a diferença entre um mixin e uma function em SASS

Tags: sass

No `Sass` temos dois casos de trecho de código reutilizável: função e o mixin.

Exemplo função:

```
@function border-default($color) {
    @return border: 1px solid $color:
}
```

Exemplo mixin:

```
@mixin border-default ($color) {
    border: 1px solid $color:
}
```

Não levando em consideração que um usa `return` e o outro não, qual é a diferença mais impactante entre uma `function` e uma `mixin`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apesar dos dois terem quase o mesmo propósito, eles tem um pequena diferença, onde mixin serve mais para incluir um bloco de código enquanto a function serve mais retorna um valor.

[What is the real difference between mixins and functions?](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/what-is-the-real-difference-between-mixins-and-functions)

Exemplo Mixin:

A seguir mixin pode aceitar argumentos e fazer cálculos. A saída deste mixin (neste caso) é uma regra CSS e será colocada onde quer que você inclue.

```
@mixin my-mixin($some-number) {
  padding: $some-number;
  margin: $some-number;
}
```

Agora vamos usar a diretiva include para inserir o código mixins.

```
.my-module {
  @include my-mixin(10px);
}
```

E aqui está o código CSS saída.

```
.my-module {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Exemplo Function:

Uma função é muito semelhante a um mixin, no entanto, a saída a partir de uma função é um único valor. Isso pode ser qualquer tipo de dados Sass, incluindo: numbers, string, colors, booleans ou lists.

A função a seguir pode aceitar 2 argumentos, $some-number e $another-number. O valor devolvido essas duas variáveis ​​são adicionadas em conjunto.

```
@function my-calculation-function($some-number, $another-number){
  @return $some-number + $another-number
}
```

Desta vez, vamos substituir o valor comum da propriedade padding com o que um trecho de [SassScript](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#sassscript) para chamar nossa função, passe-os argumentos e incluir no nosso código CSS saída.

```
.my-module {
  padding: my-calculation-function(10px, 5px);
}
```

E aqui está o código CSS saída.

```
.my-module {
  padding: 15px;
}
```

Esse link abaixo mostra mais alguns bons exemplos disso além do que citei aqui:

[Using pure Sass functions to make reusable logic more useful](http://thesassway.com/advanced/pure-sass-functions)

Repare que no próprio exemplo que citou, não é possível retornar várias propriedades como no mixins:

```
@function border-default($color) {
   @return border: 1px solid $color:
}


@mixin my-mixin($some-number) {
  padding: $some-number;
  margin: $some-number;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ambos possuem quase a mesma função, assim como o `@extend` - apesar de ter um `output` um pouco mais diferenciado (mais relacionado a questões de performance e `DRY` eu diria).

A grosso modo falando, esta é a diferença entre básica entre ambas:

- `@mixin`: Usado para retornar um bloco de código;
- `@function`: Usado para retornar um valor através de `@return` seguindo o método `SASS`

O que vai diferenciar um `@mixin` de uma `@function`, é o propósito ao qual se está usando, inclusive com uso de ambas em uma mesma chamada.

Exemplo:

```
.minha_classe {
    @include shadow(true, #000);
}

@mixin shadow($material, $cor) {
    box-shadow: calcShadow($material, $cor);
}

@function calcShadow($material, $cor) {
    @if $material {
        @return 0 3px 6px rgba($cor, .24);
    } @else {
        @return 0 5px 10px rgba($cor, .86);
    }
}
```

Apesar de você poder mesclar o `@mixin` com o `@function` e criar apenas um bloco de calculo e retorno, deste modo você mantém seu código mais organizado e, se em outra ocasião, for necessário fazer o mesmo cálculo, basta chamar a função ao invés de criar um novo `@mixin` (ou `@function`) com aquela finalidade exclusivamente.

---

Eu, particularmente, tenho usado mais `@function` para gerar animações, onde determino, por exemplo, a direção e amplitude, retorno os valores e monto o código.

---

#### Complementar

Complementar ao `@mixin` existe o `@extend` que gera um `output` de `css` semelhante, porém diferente. Este sim possui um impacto em performance e uma diferença maior no uso. Caso tenha interesse, recomendo também buscar mais informação a respeito dele.