# Qual a diferença e quando utilizar @mixin e @extend em SASS?

Tags: css, sass

Tanto o `@mixin` como o `@extend` parecem ter o mesmo objetivo:

> Adicionar um bloco de código padrão para uma classe.

Mas se possuem essa mesma finalidade, qual a diferença entre eles? E quando devo utilizar um ou outro?

Comment: Relacionando: [Qual é a diferença entre um mixin e uma function em SASS](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/112485/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-um-mixin-e-uma-function-em-sass)

Comment: Sim, mas o comparativo entre `extend` e `function` é amplo de mais. Já a relação `mixin` vs `extend` é mais próxima. Por exemplo, `function` e `extend` possuem uma distinção bem clara, o que não é o caso de um `mixin` e um `extend`.

Answer (score 10):

A utilização de `@mixin` e `@extend` pode parecer semelhante e ter a mesma finalidade, apesar de isso ser verdade, elas possuem propósitos diferentes bem como seus prós e contras. Ambas, se utilizadas de modo errado, podem se tornar uma baita dor de cabeça.

No começo a gente pode tender a utilizar um ou outro aos montes devido a praticidade que eles nos dão para escrever `SASS`. Com um `@mixin` ou `@extend` você pode resumir inúmeras linhas de códigos. Mas é ai que mora o perigo..

Muitas vezes o que escrevemos em `SASS` parece perfeitamente prático e perfeito, tudo parece em ordem, mantendo o princípio de `DRY`, mas tudo vai embora quando olhamos nosso código compilado para `CSS`.

Por exemplo, o código a seguir pode parecer perfeito em `SASS`:

```
@mixin placeHolder {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
.classe1 {
    @include placeholder;
}
.classe2 {
    @include placeholder;
}
.classe3 {
    @include placeholder;
}
.classe4 {
    @include placeholder;
}
.classe5 {
    @include placeholder;
}
```

Mas o `CSS` gerado seria este:

```
.classe1 {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
.classe2 {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
.classe3 {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
.classe4 {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
.classe5 {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
```

Todo o princípio `DRY`, manutenção de código e simplicidade que em `SASS` parecia perfeita, foi por água abaixo...

Mas é aí que entra o `@extend` para a salvação! Veja a mesma lógica com a utilização de `@extend`:

```
%placeHolder {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
.classe1 {
    @extend %placeHolder;
}
.classe2 {
    @extend %placeHolder;
}
.classe3 {
    @extend %placeHolder;
}
.classe4 {
    @extend %placeHolder;
}
.classe5 {
    @extend %placeHolder;
}
```

Gerando o seguinte código:

```
.classe1,
.classe2,
.classe3,
.classe4,
.classe5 {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
```

Perfeito, agora nós conseguimos manter o código simples, limpo, em poucas linhas de código.

### MAS.....

Apesar de isso ser verdade, é uma verdade parcial. A utilização de `@extend` quando feita de modo abusivo pode quebrar todo o princípio básico de seu uso e gerar muitas classes com poucas propriedades, tornando seu código final extremamente bagunçado, com repetição de classes, voltando a estaca zero.

**Mas então qual devo usar? E quando devo usar?**

Um macete básico que gosto de lembrar é o seguinte:

- Mixin: Utilize para gerar seu código de modo dinâmico através de variáveis;
- Extend: Utilize para elementos comuns mas que haverá pouca repetição;

Por exemplo, vamos supor que você possua um botão com o mesmo estilo porém com alguns estados de cores. Você poderia fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
@mixin corBotao($cor, $corHover) {
    border: 1px solid $cor;
    color: $cor;
    &:hover {
        background: $cor;
        color: $corHover;
    }
}
.button--azul {
    @include corBotao(blue, white);
    background: transparent;
    width: 64px;
    height: 48px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Deste modo você irá gerar o seguinte código:

```
.button--azul {
    background: transparent;
    width: 64px;
    height: 48px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    /* Gerado pelo mixin */
    border: 1px solid blue;
    color: blue;
    &:hover {
        background: blue;
        color: white;
    }
}
```

Com isso você pode gerar diversos botões com cores diferentes sem precisar definir manualmente qual cor cada botão terá.

Para exemplificar o uso do `@mixin`, pode partir do mesmo exemplo anterior e melhorar nosso código. As propriedades de `width`, `height`, etc.. São comuns em todos os botões, seja ele azul, vermelho, verde, etc.. Então apenas essas propriedades podemos converter para o uso do `@extend`:

```
@mixin corBotao($cor, $corHover) {
    border: 1px solid $cor;
    color: $cor;
    &:hover {
        background: $cor;
        color: $corHover;
    }
}
%padraoBotao {
    background: transparent;
    width: 64px;
    height: 48px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}

.button--azul {
    @include corBotao(blue, white);
    @extend %padraoBotao;
}
.button--verde {
    @include corBotao(green, white);
    @extend %padraoBotao;
}
.button--vermelho {
    @include corBotao(red, white);
    @extend %padraoBotao;
}
```

O exemplo acima irá gerar o seguinte código final:

```
.button--azul,
.button--verde,
.button--vermelho {
    background: transparent;
    width: 64px;
    height: 48px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}
.botao--azul {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    color: blue;
    &:hover {
        background: blue;
        color: white;
    }
}
.botao--verde {
    border: 1px solid green;
    color: green;
    &:hover {
        background: green;
        color: white;
    }
}
.botao--vermelho {
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: red;
    &:hover {
        background: red;
        color: white;
    }
}
```

Veja como o código final se manteve limpo, organizado, objetivo e mantendo boas práticas.

O que não seria recomendado, seria utilizar o mesmo extend para outro elemento, por mais que ele possua a mesma característica.

Outro exemplo que eu, particularmente, utilizo o `@mixin` é para códigos pequenos que serão utilizados em algumas classes, por exemplo o uso de `display: flex;`. Como ainda precisamos dos `vendor-prefix`, eu não quero escrever todos eles à mão, mas também não quero gerar um agrupamento de classes complemante sem relação, só por partilharem do mesmo `display`. Para isso eu utilizo um mixin, mas é um uso controlado com um objetivo bem específico.

---

Como visto nos exemplos, cada um possui um uso bem específico e destinado. Apesar de serem semelhantes `DENTRO DO SASS`, quando olhamos nosso `CSS` eles possuem resultados bem distintos que podem piorar seu código final ao invés de melhorar.

Mas, apesar de toda essa diferença, lembre-se que não é uma regra a ser seguida a risca (como eu mesmo a quebro de vez enquando), tudo se trata de um planejamento e organização do seu código.

Para mais guias de boas práticas em `CSS` e `SASS` recomendo [ver este projeto](https://github.com/celsomtrindade/CSS-Style-Guide) que estou elaborando no `github`, ele está em desenvolvimento constante e também aceito contribuições! Aliás, elas são mais do que bem vindas. Mais experiências geram melhores práticas.