# CSS, minha classe pode herdar do Bootstrap

Tags: css

Tenho um sistema com Look and Feel antigo. A ideia é alterar para boorstrap. PORÉM com a menor quantidade alteração possível.

Exemplo concreto. Os botões usam a classe css fwButton. Teria como fazer essa classe herdar as propriedades das classes btn btn-primary do Bootstrap 4 ?

Sem alterar todas as chamadas html de class="fwButton" para class="btn btn-primary" e sem copiar as propriedades das classes btn btn-primary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bjverde, utilize `@extend`

Porém, muitos autores desencorajam desenvolvedores a usarem esse recurso. O motivo é o CSS gerado.

Por exemplo, digamos que temos uma classe `.error` e queremos usar os estilos dela em outra classe.

```
.error {
  color: red;
}

.icon--error {
  @extend .error;
}
```

O CSS gerado será o seguinte:

```
.error, .icon--error {
  color: red;
}
```

Mas atende ao que você precisa.

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: obrigado só hoje consegui entender que preciso do SASS para conseguir a sua dica. O link complementa a pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/121684/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-e-quando-utilizar-mixin-e-extend-em-sass